# Как получить все строки из таблицы из определенной колонки

Tags: java

У меня есть вот такой запрос в бд и массив `playersNames`, как мне записать в `playersNames` все профессии где `name` равно какому-то моему имени?

```
try {
    PreparedStatement statement = plugin.getConnection()
            .prepareStatement("SELECT job FROM " + table + " WHERE name=?");
    statement.setString(1, name);

    ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
    if (results.next()) {
        return true;
    }
    ArrayList<String> playersNames = new ArrayList<>();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Может заменить `if (results.next()) {` на `while (results.next()) { playersNames.add(results.getString('job'); }`?

Answer (score 0):

> Как мне записать в playersNames все профессии

Итерируйтесь с помощью цикла `while (results.next())`:

```
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
ResultSet results = null;
try {
    connection = plugin.getConnection();
    statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT job FROM " + table + " WHERE name=?");
    statement.setString(1, name);
    List<String> playersNames = new ArrayList<>();
    results = statement.executeQuery();
    while (results.next()) {
        playersNames.add(results.getString("job"));
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try { results.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
    try { statement.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
    //закрытие соединения при необходимости
    //try { connection.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
}
```

Существенный недостаток вашего кода - вы не закрываете открытые ресурсы: `ResultSet`, `PreparedStatement` и, скорее всего, `Connection` ("скорее всего", т.к. вы получаете подключение из какого-то плагина и, возможно, вы его планируете переиспользовать - тут только вам виднее, хотя обычно соединение закрывают и освобождают ресурсы после выполнения запроса - это позволит, например, вернуть подключение в пул и затем переиспользовать).
Неплохой ответ по закрытию ресурсов - [Closing Database Connections in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225221/closing-database-connections-in-java)